# match a string without having spaces with regex

Tags: php, regex, match

this is my string I want to get only "GG-00"

```
$html = "
<td class="P12"> n                Gg-08n            </td>
<li class="P13"> n                GG-00n            </li>
<li class="P122"> n                Gt-90n            </li>
<img class="m43" src="../a.img"></img>
//and more like that//
"
preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}/', $html, $output);
```

I want to get only GG-00 which in

```
<li class="P13">
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('/GG-00/',` .. as good as any considering the information provided

Comment: It will be changed every time but it will be like that AA-11 or FV-22

Comment: what's the EXACT pattern? we are not psychic

Comment: @ss.5 can you please be more specific? From your other comments I understand you have one string with the entire HTML page and you want to extract `[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}` if it is within a `<li class="P12">`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's certainly not very clear what you want to do exactly. Also, what other characters can appear within the `li`?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (assuming it's *always* two capitals followed by a hyphen and two numbers):

```
/[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}/
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what do you want to extract. If you want to extract only that specific "GG-00" you can go with:

```
$html = '<li class="P12"> n                GG-00n            </li>';
preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}/', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Will output:

```
Array ( [0] => GG-00 )
```

If your problem is more complex than this single case you can also think of reading HTML DOM and getting all LI elements

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<li class="P12"> n                GG-00n            </li>');
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $html = $doc->saveHtml();
    preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}/', $html, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: very helpful but my strings which is in $html are many, so how to find this class and match [A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}? I tried this but not working "$this->match('/<li class="P12"> n\([A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}\)<\/li>/ms', $html, 1);"

Comment: Can you please share more complex example? Can you show me what would you like as input and what as output? I assume: input string, output array of string ("gg-00" etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following:

`/[A-Z].-[0-9]./gm`

here is the php:

```
<?php

$matches = null;
preg_match('/[A-Z].-[0-9]./m', '<li class="P12"> n                GG-00n            </li>', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the things you can do;

```
$string = '<li class="P12"> n                GG-00n            </li>';
$string = explode('<li class="P12"> n                ', $string);
$string = explode('            </li>', $string[1]);
$thecode = $string[0];
```

With this there can also be different codes...

Comment: Thank you but I wanted with regex like /[A-Z].-[0-9]./gm